# Multer GridFs Storage Associate req.user to metadata

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I can upload a file to my MongoDB using multer-gridfs-storage, but I am having trouble associating the file with user, what i want is to be able to pass req.user which i get from passportjs to the file metadata

```
// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);


// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
gfs.collection('uploads');
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
  crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      const filename = buf.toString('hex') + 
      path.extname(file.originalname);
      const fileInfo = {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: 'uploads',
        metadata: {
          user : // I want to pass here req.user 
        }
      };
      resolve(fileInfo);
    });
  });
},
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement like this:

```
// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);


// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
gfs.collection('uploads');
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
  crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      const filename = buf.toString('hex') + 
      path.extname(file.originalname);
      const user = req.user;
      const fileInfo = {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: 'uploads',
        metadata: user
      };
      resolve(fileInfo);
    });
  });
},
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

Comment: i've tried your solution but it gives me on the database 'metadata: null' , even tough req.user is not null when i log it in the console

Comment: Do you have access to req in the fileinfo? create a var and assign the req.user to it. I have updated the code